# how to determine whether the image is made to the device or downloaded from the outside iOS?

Tags: ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller, exif, alassetslibrary

Actually my question in title, how to determine is image made on device or  it downloaded from outside.

I use ALAssetsLibrary and standard UIImagePickerController, to load images but they can return an image which user saved from internet or get from email, I need to switch images which made on device with camera and other.

Feel free to ask any questions, i hope community will help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to read dictionary like:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
//your code
NSLog(@"INFO: %@", info);
}
```

and you will see that there is a key with device information:

```
"{TIFF}" =         {
            DateTime = "2012:09:13 16:59:41";
            Make = Apple;
            Model = "iPhone 4S";
            Software = "5.1.1";
            XResolution = 72;
            YResolution = 72;
        };
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the source as `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`. This specifies the device’s Camera Roll album as the source for the image picker controller. See the documentation on [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class)

Comment: Nope, not works, i just saved foot from internet and it shows on camera roll, i need to determine photos made on this device only.